# Git, why working on other branch still updates master branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using git as my version control. 
I'm using IntelliJ Idea and when I create a new branch, it shows I'm in this branch. However when I switch to master branch in order to merge that branch, git is saying everything is uptodate. What is the problem?

I'm using git v.1.9.0

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about what you've done? Switching back to master will say that it's upto date because no new commits have been added to that branch which need to be pushed back to the remote.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim thanks, you are right. My mistake was because of not adding changes. After I add it and commit it problem solved. Please write your comment as answer. Thanks again.